# Consider the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.A partition $\Pi $ of $A$ is collection of disjoint sets whose union is $A$

Tags: contest-math, integer-partitions, set-partition

Consider the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.A partition $\Pi $ of $A$ is collection of disjoint sets whose union is $A$. For example, $\Pi_1=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4,5\},\{6,7,8,9\}\}$ and $\Pi _2 =\{\{1\},\{2,5\},\{3,7\},\{4,6,8,9\}\}$ can be considered as partitions of $A$. For, each $\Pi$ partition ,we consider the function $\pi$ defined on the elements of$A$. $\pi (x)$ denotes the cardinality of the subset in $\Pi$ which contains $x$. For, example in case of $\Pi_1$ , $\pi_1(1)=\pi_1(2)=2$, $\pi_1(3)=\pi_1(4)=\pi_1 (5)=3$, and $\pi_1(6)=\pi_1(7)=\pi_1(8)=\pi_1(9)=4$. For $\Pi_2$ we have $\pi_2(1)=1$, $\pi_2(2)=\pi_2(5)=2$, $\pi_2(3)=\pi_2(7)=2$ and $\pi_2(4) = \pi_2(6) = \pi_2(8) = \pi_2(9) = 4$ Given any two partitions $\Pi$ and $\Pi '$, show that there are two numbers $x$ and $y$ in $A$, such that  $\pi(x)=\pi(y)$ and $\pi′(x)=\pi′(y)$.

***Source:*** Mathematical Talent Reward Programme 2016

First of all in this question i haven't understood about the function. What are $\Pi_1$, $\Pi_2$, $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ ? What are the difference between them ? The given conditions are making the functions more complicated ? And also how to apprach the problem ?

I spent hours to understand in exam hall as well as in home for this but got nothing?

Comment: $\Pi$ is not a function here.  It is a partition.  A partition is defined in the question as some way of *partitioning* the elements of the set into disjoint subsets.  We start using subscripts as a way to denote different partitions.  The problem gave as examples two partitions who they label as $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ respectively.  Now... for a given partition, $\pi$ will be a function which takes an element as an input and outputs the size of the part in the partition which contains $x$.  Since we are talking about multiple partitions, use subscripts to clarify *which* partition $\pi$ was...

Comment: ...in reference to.  So... we were given an example of a partition $\Pi_1$.  So, we have $\pi_1(3)$ gives the size of the part which contained $3$ in the first partition, which if you look back you have $\Pi_1 = \{\{1,2\},\color{red}{\{3,4,5\}},\{6,7,8,9\}\}$ the part containing $3$ happened to be of size three.  Now... later when they ask the actual question, they talk about two partitions which rather than labeled with subscripts they label the two partitions $\Pi$ and $\Pi'$ with corresponding functions $\pi$ and $\pi'$.

Comment: Ok thanks now i understood what that two are meaning.

Comment: Your goal... is to show that given *any* two partitions of $\{1,2,\dots,9\}$ (*not necessarily the partitions given as an example*), you can always find some two elements such that for each element the *size* (*though not necessarily the contents*) of the part containing the element in the first partition is the same as the size of the part containing that same element in the second partition.

Comment: So in the above example for $\Pi_1,\,\Pi_2$ the only $x$ satisfying $\pi_1(x)=\pi_2(x)$ is $2$?

Comment: It would sure seem that way, wouldn't it... which makes me question the validity of the problem.

Comment: Maybe it should be $\pi(x)=\pi'(y),\,\pi(y)=\pi'(x)$?

Comment: Well... if we were to assume there is a correct phrasing to the question where the claim were valid... and there were no restrictions on what types of partitions we were looking at beyond that they were partitions of $\{1,2,\dots,9\}$, then it should work in particular for the two extreme examples of partitions... $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\dots,\{9\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2,3,\dots,9\}\}$... but in such a case $\pi(i)=1$ for all $i$ and $\pi'(j)=9$ for all $j$... so I can't imagine any scenarios for which both a $\pi$ and a $\pi'$ appear in the same equation.

Comment: So then... perhaps it is meant to be $\pi(x)=\pi(y)$ and $\pi'(x)=\pi'(y)$

Comment: I think @Alexey Burdin is right because one counter example is $\Pi=\{\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\}$ and $\Pi'=\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}, \{7,8,9\}\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz seems true for this version, checked with the [python code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emYetusROdkpdDS0Qx5vjTPdPYZmFvpr/view?usp=sharing). A minimum ($2$ such values, not $3$ or more) is obtained on e.g. $\{\{8, 9, 7\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}\},\; \{\{8, 9, 5, 6\}, \{3, 4, 7\}, \{1, 2\}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the likely correct condition is $ \pi (x) = \pi (y), \pi'(x) = \pi'(y)$.

---

**Crux:** Let $ \pi^l$ denote the elements whose subset in $ \Pi$ have exactly $l$ elements.

Show that

1. $\pi^l \neq \emptyset$ for at most 3 values of $l$.
2. $|\pi ^l|$ is a multiple of $l$.

This was hinted at in the partitions $\Pi_1, \Pi_2$.
Using the example in the problem, we have $\pi_2^1 = \{1\}, \pi_2^2 = \{2, 3, 5, 7 \}, \pi_2^4 =\{4, 6, 8, 9 \}$.

> Suppose there are 4 sets with a distinct number of elements. Then $ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 > 9$, hence a contradiction.

> $|\pi^l| = $ number of subsets of size $l \times  l$.

---

Suppose that such $ \Pi_1, \Pi_2$ exist where $ \left( \pi_1 (n), \pi_2(n) \right)$ are all distinct.

Let the image of $ \pi_2$ be $ \subset \{ i, j, k \}$. (From above, it has at most 3 elements.)

If $ | \pi_2^l |> 3$, then consider $\pi_1 (n) $ where $ n \in \pi_2^l$.
Since $\pi_1(n)$ takes on 3 values, by the pigeonhole principle, 2 of these are the same value, which is a contradiction.

Otherwise, we have $ |\pi^l | \leq 3$.
Since $ \sum |\pi^l| = 9$, hence  we must have $ |\pi^i| = |\pi ^j | = |\pi^k| = 3$.
However, this is only possible if $\{ i, j, k \} \in \{ 1, 3 \}$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, such partitions do not exist.

---

Note: There is another approach that uses $ | \left\{ ( \pi_1 (n), \pi_2(n) )\right\}| \leq 3 \times 3 = 9$.
If it is 8 or fewer, pigeonhole works directly to give us the 2 elements with identical values.
If it is exactly 9, start doing casework, which ends up being very similar to the above. This was how I first did the problem, before rewriting the solution.